# Skip back in a file in python

Tags: python

I am reading in a file using

```
for line in fin:
    process(line)
```

However, I would sometimes like skip back some lines in the file and just carry on from there. I won't know the number of lines in advance as it depends on calculations in the code. So I would like it to be something like

```
for line in fin:
    x = process(line)
    if (x == 23):
        skip back xxx lines and continue
```

How can you do this in python?

Is this something that can be done with mmap for example? The file is large so I don't want to just store the whole thing in memory.

Comment: How large? If you designed the file format, consider changing it so it can be parsed easily in a single forwards sweep.

Comment: Just a remark on your code here: `for line in fin.readlines()` loops over a list of lines in your memory. `for line in fin` however would read a line from the file, then read another etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
In [11]: from collections import deque

In [12]: cache = deque(maxlen=max_skip_back)

In [13]: for line in fin:
   ....:     line = line.strip()
   ....:     cache.append(line)
   ....:     x = process(line)
   ....:     if x == 23:
   ....:         for line in cache[-this_skip_back:]:
   ....:             process(line)
```

This won't read the whole file into memory. deques drop their first elements if they get longer than `maxlen`.

Comment: This could work if I could guess the maximum I will ever need to skip back.

Comment: @felix: Edited my answer to allow for a variable number of lines that you skip back.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
lines = fin.readlines()
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    x = process(lines[i])
    if x == 23:
        i -= num_lines
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Maybe turn that if-else into a ternary?

Comment: @Basic `i += -num_lines if x == 23 else 1` looks far uglier

Comment: @Nirk I'd disagree but then it's a matter of preference

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  It just seems up set a variable i but not actually read the old line back in.

Comment: Oh that just reads in the whole input. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Isn't that just going to turn into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest recording the position of each line in an array as you go, using the tell() method on the file object.  This provides the offset to the location of each line as you encounter it.  Then when you want to skip back, you use the f.seek() to jump backwards to a specified locations.

For example:

```
linestarts = []
f = open(myfile,"r")
...
linestarts.append(f.tell()) # save each line
f.readline()  # do stuff reading a line
...
# want to jump back 3 lines for some reason
f.seek( linestarts[-3] )
```

Of course, the other option is to cache the last few lines in your own code, but that's what stdio is
already doing for you.

Comment: That's awesome! I knew it must be possible to keep track of where in a file you are!

Comment: That is great, thanks. The downside is that linestarts grows with the file size I suppose so the amount of space you save over just storing the lines may vary. Maybe you could make linestarts  into a dequeue if you knew the maximum number of lines you would ever skip back.